# How return value of function behave differently for variable and array

Tags: c, function

I have following case:

```
char *func1()
{
   char val[]="This is test!";
   return val;
}
```

Now here i know that `char val[]` is local array to the function and it will not longer available as function returns.

Now why this not true for following case?

```
char func2()
{
   char val='C';
   return val;
}
```

Have tested it

```
int main()
{
   printf("output1 :: %s \n",func1()); // print garbage characters
   printf("output2 :: %c \n",func2()); // print `C`
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `char func2()` returns a *copy* of the function's local variable `var`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C returns by value. When you write `return val;` in `func2`, a copy of `val` is returned. It does not matter that the original `val` is destroyed, you still have the copy.

In `func1` you return a copy of a pointer to `val`. This is not the same as a copy of `val`. There are no copies of `val` in `func1`. Arrays and pointers are different; and pointers do not have any identity with the thing they point to. Once `val` is destroyed, you can no longer use a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

The function `func2` returns a copy of the variable `char val`.